# Simulation of 2D vs 3D electromagnetic waves

Tags: simulation, dimensions, em

If you using a simulation tool that allows you to simulate behaviour electromagnetic waves in an environment. What differences are there in terms of doing the simulation in 2D vs 3D?

Does doing the simulation done in 2D necessarily mean your results (power of the EM waves) in reality i.e 3D will be less? If so then how do you estimate this loss?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to shield a PCB (assume 2_D) from an external switching Regulator waveform.

You have choice of shielding: standard 35 micron copper foil, 1/16 inch aluminum, 1/16 inch steel (mu of 1,000).

Which to use? The 3_D seems essential.

Answer (score 1):

2D is mostly correct if you have all signals on a single layer, which you might be able to pull off with some high speed designs,

3D is when you have multiple layers, or larger components that extend off the plane of the PCB, e.g. large switching inductors, and you want them in your model,

Due to this, 3D EM tends to gives a "more complete" image of what is happening to your signal, usually at the cost of longer computation times per run for the same board.

Both of these simulations are computing the vector field of the EM waves (Voltage and magnetism will always be perpendicular) but you end up with a second axis that perpendicular vector can face along in 3D which can lead to lower or higher values in areas depending on where your measuring.

Answer (score 1):

as @analogsystemsrf implies:

You use a 2D simulation, where you know that 2D is sufficient for the modeling of the physical system. If it is sufficient, then the results will be right.

If the results aren't the same (up to numerical error) as in correct 3D modelling, then your assumption that 2D modelling suffices was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty clueless when it comes to EM simulations and viz.  However, I did spend some time in biophysics and geophysics- and in general I noticed that the other scientists (the smart ones lol) would tend to focus on the lowest dimensional representation of their problem domains that still encapsulated the essence of whatever dynamics they were studying.  So cellular movement through chemotaxis was reduced to 2-dimensions handily, even though it became a somewhat comical approximation of a more accurate model.  These weren't lazy guys, either.

Maybe the requirements for the project at hand will be a better guide for what kind of accuracy / model you need. I'm going to go ask my own question now about EM viz- you inspired me. :)